# Diagnosing page faults in non-paged areas with good ram?

Tags: windows-8, memory

Here's the rundown: my system boots and operates fine, but I get intermittent blue screens (often referencing page faults) and applications crash at random complaining of memory access violations.

Both Windows' built-in memory diagnostic tool and Memtest86 have given my memory a clean bill of health, but the problem persists. Microsoft mentioned that corrupt hard disks could also cause this, but chkdsk swears that there is no problem there, either.

The only other symptom I can report is that it happens more often in multithreaded applications, or when the computer is multitasking--although apparently *not* when Prime95 is the application in question.

Where should I look next, and how?

Comment: upload the dumps to a cloud service and post a link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no idea how to diagnose the problem, but it seems to have been a bad connection with the ram. The only support I have for this theory is that taking the sticks out and shoving them back in solved the problem. Why it didn't occur in testing is also a mystery.

Going to put this down to "things get hotter in summer" and call it good.